# C++: Memory Leak;Vector-like class

Tags: c++, vector, memory-leaks

Im beginnger in C++ and try to creat container class which is similar to the Vector. this class should works like a Vector for all type of data and could be used in range-based for loop.
i wrote the hpp but my tutor says that there is a memory leak ,I think i deleted all the dynamic memory,where could be the problem?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;
template<class T>
class Customvector
{
public:
    Customvector();
    ~Customvector();
    int size();
    int free_capacity();
    void add(T& temp);
    int& operator[](int index);
    void grow();

    class iterator {
        public:
            iterator(T* ptr) : ptr(ptr) {}
            iterator operator++() { iterator i(ptr); ++ptr; return i; }
            bool operator!=(const iterator & other) { return ptr != other.ptr; }
            const T& operator*() const { return *ptr; } 
        private:
            T* ptr;
        };

    iterator begin() const { return iterator(&_elements[0]); }
    iterator end() const { return iterator(&_elements[0]+_size); }
private:
    T*  _elements;
    int _size;
    int _capacity;
    int DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
};

template<class T>
Customvector<T>::Customvector()
{
    DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 4;
    _capacity = DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
    _size = 0;
    _elements = new T[_capacity];

}
template<class T>
Customvector<T>::~Customvector()
{
    delete[] _elements;

}
template<class T>
void Customvector<T>::add(T& temp)
{
    grow(); //check if the capacity is full, if so,increase capacity by DEFAULt_CAPACITY;
    _elements[_size++]= temp;

}
template<class T>
int Customvector<T>::size()
{
    return _size;
}

template<class T>
int Customvector<T>::free_capacity()
{
    int free_c = _capacity - _size;
    return free_c;
}


template<class T>
int& Customvector<T>::operator[](int index) {
    if (index<0 || index>_capacity)
    {
        cout << "index beyond limit" << endl;
        return _elements[0];
    };
    return _elements[index];
}

template<class T    >
void Customvector<T>::grow() 
{ 
    if (_capacity == _size) 
    {
        _capacity += DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
        T* p = new T[_capacity];
        std::copy(_elements, _elements + _size,p);
        delete[] _elements;
        _elements = p;
    };

}
```

Comment: You might want to read about [rules of three, five and zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: For one, you don't have a destructor in your iterator class which is probably where you'd `delete [] ptr`

Comment: Also, you have *undefined behavior* in your `operator[]` function if you pass in an illegal index and the vector is empty. The contents of the data you allocate is *indeterminate*, and using it in any way except initializing the data will lead to said undefined behavior.

Comment: Did you learn about exceptions yet? They cause a leak in your code.

Comment: @TriHard8 And the OP should not delete any data there, as the pointer passed in is from the actual array in the `CustomVector` class.

Comment: @TriHard8 the iterator in this case just iterates over `_elements` for viewing / modifying. `CustomVector` is responsible for clearing memory.

Comment: Oh, and that `operator[]` function, shouldn't it return something else?

Comment: This check `index>_capacity` in `operator []` should be `index>=_capacity`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg you mean the return type i wrote for operator [] is wrong?

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis  yep,I noticed that error too,thx.

Comment: Try using something else than `int` (like e.g. `std::string`) and try to build. You have hard-coded the return-type as `int&`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i changed it to T& ,thx.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg how should i avoid this  undefined behavior ? i mean it seems to me a right way to read the element by [ ].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only leaky case that I can find is in `grow`:

```
    ...
    T* p = new T[_capacity];
    std::copy(_elements, _elements + _size,p); // may throw an exception
    delete[] _elements;
    _elements = p;
    ...
```

If copying of a contained element throws, then `_elements` still points to the old array and the new array pointed by `p` leaks. You can resolve this with `unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<T[]> p(new T[_capacity]);
std::copy(_elements, _elements + _size, p.get()); // it's OK if this throws, unique_ptr will take care of the memory
delete[] _elements;
_elements = p.release();
```

Using `unique_ptr` for `_elements` too would simplify some of your code and improve correctness.

Comment: I don´t really understand  how an exception works here,i mean:
std::copy(_elements, _elements + _size,p); // if here throw an exception it will jump out of whole scope here or just this single line of code?

Comment: @LiZeng exceptions work here the same way they do everywhere. When an object is thrown, the scope is exited. And if the object wasn't caught by any catch expression, then the higher scopes are recursively exited until the thrown object is caught.